# Normalizing Database Table

Tags: database, normalization

I was asked an interview question and I want to confirm if I did it right or not. There is a table called Employee saving Employee information alogwith monthly salaries(Assume that this table currently have a year record only)

```
Employee(ID,Name,Month,Salary)
```

Sample Data:

```
ID  Name Month Salary
1    A    Jan   2500
1    A    Feb   3000
2    B    Jan   4500
2    B    Feb   6500
```

The question was:

> Is this table schema alright? If not how will you resolve it?

I normalized the table and want to know if this is the right way to normalize the above table?

```
Employee(ID,Name)
tblSalary(ID,Emp_ID,Month,Salary)
```

Please excuse me if its a very basic question

Comment: If the employee was hired to only work for one year, you're good.

Comment: Looks good to me, but as the interviewer I'd ask why you did that? What principle does it serve? What kind of criterion did the first version violate?

Comment: I'd also want to know why `tblSalary` needs the `ID` column.

Comment: ...but what is month and salary?

Comment: @Thilo tbh, I thought that if I want to save info of a new Employee who hasn't been given any salary then the rest f the fields would be null. the table design just didnt look good to me. Can you please explain? Suppose you are my interviewer and you want to explain why it should be normalized

Comment: IMHO, your's and theirs are wrong, but until you clarify what Month is (is it the month of the specific payment?) it would be hard to say. Is Salary *their* recurring salary or the specific payment. In short, you have an incomplete date. How would anyone reasonably search for all salaries for a given year, for example?

Comment: From a normalisation point of view your answer seems correct to me but I'd say if the Employee table doesn't have a tbl prefix neither should the Salary table (I've never liked prefixes on tables, particularly not when one of the conceptual advantages of SQL is that a table can be replaced by a view without modifying the client code so a prefix that says "this is a table" seems like bad form).

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I have edited post with sample data

Comment: You're right for splitting it where you did and it's clear the salary is the sum of the monthly payment. Where I would've improved it is handle the fact that, if the employee is worth keeping, there will be multiple entries for the same employee and month and no clear way to distinguish which year it occurred; that seems like basic information needed even if you're tracking it by month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done it right according to:

First Normal Form

1. Eliminate repeating groups in individual table.
2. Create a separate table for each set of related data.
3. Identify each set of related data with a primary key.

Only thing to point out is your "month" entity which i would change to a date instead, as it limits the employee to be employeed for only one year (as pointed out by another comment)

Comment: If I dont normalize,We have to enter Employee information for all months resulting in repeating groups. Is that what you mean by repeating groups. Right?

Comment: @HumaAli exactly ... that will result in redundant information (repeating groups or rows if you like) ..

Comment: But there seems to be a redundant primary key now. The rows in tbl_salary are already identified by "emp_id, month". Why the extra "id"?

Comment: @Thilo True .. you could skip the tblSalary ID and just use the primary employee key from the Employee table.